# How can I append int variable to string to print path of my DFS algorithm?

Tags: c++, concatenation, depth-first-search

I am trying to print the path through a graph made by my DFS algorithm. I am having errors which I do not understand.

```
void GraphTraversal::printPath(std::vector<const Node *> &path)
{
    string myPath;
    
     for(int i = 0; i<path.size(); i++)
     {
    
        string dfspath = to_string(dfspath[i].getNodeID()); // i get an error here - expression must have class type but it has type "char"
        std::cout<<dfspath; 
     }
     paths.insert(myPath);
}
```

I have coded my DFS algorithm as such.

```
void GraphTraversal::DFS(set<const Node *> &visited, vector<const Node *> &path, const Node *src, const Node *dst)
{
    visited.insert(src);
    path.push_back(src);
    if (src == dst) 
    {
       printPath();
    }

    for(const auto &e: src->getOutEdges())
    {
        if(!visited.count(e->getDst())){
        DFS( visited, path, e->getDst(), dst);
        }
    }
    visited.erase(src);
    path.pop_back();
}
```

The output I would like from my printPath method is for string singlePath to output "START: 1->2->4->5->END" with the digits being the nodeID.

Comment: [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: whoops i have used that. i forgot to include it. i just edited

Comment: What is `Node`?  You really should have written a small `main` program that demonstrates the issue.  This has nothing to do with depth-first-search.

Comment: `string dfspath = to_string(dfspath[i].getNodeID());` -- Explain what this line is supposed to do, especially the `dfspath[i]` part, where you assume there is a member function that a `char` has called `getNodeID`.

Comment: I want to retrieve the individual NodeID of the path founded by my DFS. then I want to append them to a string and I want to concatenate START, -> and END to the string so it shows me the entire path followed by the DFS. the dfspath[i] i thought would help add the node id to the string. but im starting to feel like its the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a `string` variable named `path`, but your parameter is already named `path`.

So `path[i]` actually refers to the `string`, not to the `vector`.

Also, `path[i]` is a `const Node*`, so you must call it's function with : `path[i]->getNodeID()`.

Comment: in visual studio code when i hover over "path[i]" it refers to the one i initialised in the function.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the `string` ?

Comment: yep. just changed it to "dfspath" and i get the same error.

Comment: Can you please post the new code ?

Comment: @Eddy101 *in visual studio code when i hover over "path[i]"* -- This is the reason why you shouldn't use "hovering over" to determine what is going in.  The `path` is `std::string`.  Second, hovering over is *not* the C++ compiler -- it is the compiler giving the error.

Comment: @Eddy101 -- Do not change the original code.  Now this answer is meaningless -- the reason for the error is exactly as given by this answer.  What you should have done is go back to the code and *add* the `Node` class, as that is part and parcel of this entire issue.

Comment: change `dfspath[i].getNodeID()` to `path[i].getNodeID()`. You want to access the `i`-th node, not the `i`-th char of the string

Comment: i get the same error if i do that. instead of saying char it says type const Node *

Comment: `path[i]->getNodeID()` (note that you can do that only if `getNodeID` is `const`).

Comment: that works now. thank you. i feel stupid for trying to access the char of the string. could you explain why it would only work while const?